# Nativescript 7 - can't do in app purchase on ios

Tags: android, ios, nativescript

I have an app developed in NativeScript 7, designed for both Android and iOS. It is basically finished except that I have a problem with the in app purchase on iOS, since it works as expected on Android.

I can load the app correctly in App Store Connect and start the verification process, but the testers fail to test the IAP because the information from them is not downloaded and therefore the window to buy does not appear.

I am using the library https://github.com/choang10/nativescript-in-app-purchase following the configuration described in it, as I said above, on Android it works correctly.

At the same time, when the app is rejected, in the IAP it tells me that an action must be carried out by the developer, but I don't see anything explicit inside, only that a red ball appears in the description text, and when I modify any letter or space turns yellow and the error that an action is needed no longer appears.

In addition, everything that has to do with bank accounts, contracts, personal information, acceptance of terms of use and others has already been configured and accepted.

I do not know if the information I have provided is sufficient, let me know, thank you very much.

Comment: Does it work in the sandbox? I am almost ready to go live with a new app using the same NS 7 & almost the same in-app purchase plugin (I'm not using a fork tho) but both Android and iOS seem to be working fine. I haven't tried with real money yet on iOS.

Comment: hi @RcoderNY, I tried with storekit in xcode successfully, but can't connect to sandbox with a tester account. I mean, y create de tester user, logout of my normal account in an IPhone 6, and download de app in testflight, but nothing happens